# Count rows containing text by mask (without having a mask)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table with a text field (~1 mil rows) in PostgreSQL db. is there an easy way to make a selection from a table in such a way that the output is the number of rows whose text field values are similar (let's say more than 80% of a text matches). Text length may vary (from 10 to 300+ characters)

| description |
| --- |
| something 1 |
| something 2 |
| something 1 |
| something 3 |
| ... |
| strange description 1 with difference in the middle |
| strange description 2 with difference in the middle |
| strange description 3 with difference in the middle |
| ... |
| trouble 1 detected in location 2 |
| trouble 2 detected in location 3 |
| trouble 5 detected in location 6 |

expected output:

| mask (auto-generated) | row count |
| --- | --- |
| something * | 5663 |
| strange description * with difference in the middle | 4434 |
| trouble * detected in location * | 543 |

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a setup for PostgreSQL so I implemented it through the SQL-Server.
Most probably it will work with PostgreSQL. If it does not work, you will also get a basic idea of how to implement in PostgreSQL.

```
create table SOQ3(description varchar(1000))

insert into SOQ3 values('something 1'),('something 2'),('something 1'),('something 3'),('strange description 1 with difference in the middle'),('strange description 2 with difference in the middle'),('strange description 3 with difference in the middle'),('trouble 1 detected in location 2'),('trouble 2 detected in location 3'),('trouble 5 detected in location 6');

select * from SOQ3;
with cte as(
select *,case when description LIKE 'something _' then  'something *'
              when description LIKE 'strange description _ with difference in the middle' then 'strange description * with difference in the middle'
              when description LIKE 'trouble _ detected in location _' then 'trouble * detected in location *'
              else description end as temp_col from SOQ3)
select temp_col, count(*) as 'row count' from cte group by temp_col;
```

Input Table :

[image]

Output Table :

[image]

Note: Change Your table name as per your requirement

Comment: Ty for your time and answer, but the main trouble here is next: I'm searching for a solution, that can bring result without using statements  like "...description LIKE..." Because there are thousands of them in my case, and they cannot be predefined manually. I want to find the way to do it automatically so the dbms finds them thyself :( thanks againg, hope you have a nice day!